# MATLAB conversion to python? Error in python due to shapes of arrays

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

***Question***

I have a Brownian motion vectorized path given below that I am trying to replicate in python. My problem is that one of the functions, highlighted as the first function in yellow is not working. Instead it is giving me an error (`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,499) (500,1000)`) due to the dimensions of the two arrays being added.

How can I recreate the array `U` using python?

The MATLAB code is from [An Algorithmic Introduction to Numerical Simulation of stochastic Differential Equations](https://www.caam.rice.edu/%7Ecox/stoch/dhigham.pdf) and is not my own code.

***MATLAB code***

[image]

***Python attempt not working***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import matlib as mb

# BPATH 3 Function along a Brownian path

T = 1
N = 500
dt = float(T/N)
M = 1000 # ntraj
t = np.arange(dt,T,dt)

## == Mean of 1000 paths == ##

dW = np.sqrt(dt)* np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, (n,M)) # all general increments
W = np.cumsum(dW, axis=1) # cumsum by column

a = mb.repmat(t,M,1)
U = np.exp(a+0.5*W) # Error is here
```

***Error message***

```
     17 W = np.cumsum(dW, axis=1) # cumsum by column
     18 a = mb.repmat(t,M,1)
---> 19 U = np.exp(a+0.5*W)
     20 
     21 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,499) (500,1000)
```

Comment: [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: Hi @wwii I have read the document but I am not understanding how this helps with the problem. Could you perhaps be more clear?

Comment: The document explains the rules for broadcasting. The array shapes need to be compatible for the operation being performed. If you understand the matlab code you wrote you should be able to craft a functional equivalent with numpy after you learn some numpy basics - that starts with spending some time with the numpy documentation. Unfortunately I am matlab challenged.

Comment: Thank you @wwii I will try and figure this out now.

Comment: in the matlab code can you tell us the shape of each element? It will point the error relatively easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to import and use `mb.repmat`.  That's used in MATLAB because it doesn't do `broadcasting` (or at least didn't until recently).  To add to the (500,1000) shape `W`, `t` needs to be (500,), expended to `(500,1)`.  I'd suggest using `linspace` for generating `t`.

Test:

```
t = np.linspace(dt,T, N)   # (500,) shape
...
U = t[:,None] + 0.5*W      # add (500,1) with (500,1000)
```

`np.arange` doesn't include the end point so your `t` was only (499,) shaped.

===

The MATLAB code, reproduced in Octave

```
>> T=1;N=500;dt=T/N;t=[dt:dt:1];
>> M=1000;
>> x=repmat(t,[M 1]);
>> W=randn(M,N);
>> Umean=mean(x+W);
```

`t` is (1,500); `x` and `W` are (1000,500) size, and thus can add elementwise.  `Umean` is (1,500) - the mean over the 1st dimension.

The `numpy` code:

```
In [1]: T = 1
   ...: N = 500
   ...: dt = float(T/N)
   ...: M = 1000 # ntraj
   ...: t = np.arange(dt,T,dt)
In [2]: t.shape
Out[2]: (499,)
In [3]: t = np.linspace(dt,T,N)
In [4]: t.shape
Out[4]: (500,)

In [6]: W=np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, (N,M))
In [7]: W.shape
Out[7]: (500, 1000)

In [8]: (t[:,None]+W).shape
Out[8]: (500, 1000)
```

`t[:,None]` is (500,1) shape, which broadcasts to (500,1000) without using `repmat`.

To get the `mean` over the size 1000 dimension we have to use:

```
In [9]: np.mean((t[:,None]+W), axis=1).shape
Out[9]: (500,)
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj . I see that the t is then (500, 1), should this not be (500, 1000) where 1000 represents M? When I run this the Umean that is being generated is non linear but the Umean is supposed to be a sloped line when you plot it rather than one with a lot of noise.

Comment: The  function elementwise would be like this:  U[i,j] = np.exp(t+0.5*W[i])

Comment: I've added some Octave and `numpy` code that hopefully clarify the dimensions in both.  Years ago I learned that getting the shapes right was 80% of the debugging battle in MATLAB.  Don't guess; test and verify.